# jQuery How to put a data in HTML (.data)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hi all i have a question, I have a web page with a datatable filled with data from my DB. I have a columns of checkbox and a button.
When i click on my button, I open a new page that generate an invoice.
I have done a script in jQuery which get the ID of my order with the checkbox.

Code of my check box ( i use bootstrap):

```
 <td><div class="ckbox ckbox-success">
         <input type="checkbox" class="select-invoice" data-idcommande="<?= $commande->getId()?>"/>
         <label for="checkboxSuccess"></label>
     </div>
  </td>
```

This is the code of my button (bootsrap too):

```
 <a class="btn btn-labeled btn-warning" href="facture-facture_groupee.html" id="invoicebtn"> <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-eur"></i></span>Facturer les commandes sélectionnées </a>
```

Now this is the script i've made when i click on my button:

```
$( "#invoicebtn" ).click(function() {
   $('.select-invoice').each(function() {
       $(this).data("idcommande");             
   }); 
});
```

This work fine (I have tested with `alert()`)

But now i want to put the id I've collected in the other page but i don't know how to do it.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my english i'm french.

Comment: You should use `$.post()` to submit the value to other page.

Comment: Thanks i will try that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to communicate between client and server.

**Client :**

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

**Server :**

```
if($_POST) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser i will check that :)

Comment: You're welcome ! Validate the answer if it helped :)

Comment: I would better rely on `if ( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['time']) ) { /* job here *. }` than a boolean check on `$_POST`, and if it needs, adding trimming the string to be sure your user did not modify the client value before post.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of my question thanks for anwsering it.

this is my JS :

```
$("#boutonfacturer").click(function () {

var checked = $('input[name="id_commande[]"]:checked');
var tab = [];
checked.each(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    tab.push(value);
});

$.post("genererfacture-facture_groupee.html",
        {
            id: tab

        }
      ).success(function(retour) { 
    console.log("Data Loaded: " + tab);

    });
});
```